# How can I make a custom RelativeLayout that implements Clickable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I was following this tutorial, as it's exactly what I need:

http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/

Unfortunately, their site is down, so I'm using the cached version:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pXvzFq7UR-sJ:www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

I'm up to the step where I create a custom `RelativeLayout` for my item's row. I'm getting some errors in the code and I don't know how to go about fixing them. For example, on these lines:

```
for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
    // Pass the information to all the child Checkable widgets
    c.setChecked(isChecked);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Checkable
```

I've never used `Checkable` before, and don't know how it works.

Could someone help implement this?

Comment: Without more code, it's difficult to tell. What is `checkableViews` for example? Do the objects it contains implement `Checkable`? Presumably not according to the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either cast the object to a Checkable object:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkableViews.size(); i++) {
    Checkable c = (Checkable) checkableViews.get(i);
    // Pass the information to all the child Checkable widgets
    c.setChecked(isChecked);
}
```

Or even better you could supply the type of object being stored in the list when you declare the list, for example:

```
List<Checkable> checkableList;
checkableList = new ArrayList<Checkable>();
```

Then your original `for` loop should work fine.